# input[type=number] placeholder color in FF29+

Tags: css, firefox, placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder="test" />
<input type="number" placeholder="test" />
```

How do I style it?

```
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Why doesn't the global placeholder work on it, even though firebug shows it's applied? Is it a bug, is it an intention?

http://jsbin.com/papad/1/edit?html,css,output

[image]

Comment: I have FF29 atm and your JSBIN shows me a nice red color :D Also: http://caniuse.com/#search=moz-placeholder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're supposed to provide all the basic info (esp. relevant code) within the question itself. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @HansWassink how strange: I've also FF29 on MacOS and I see a gray placeholder for the second input

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LKC2K/2/ - does that work for you?

Comment: @SW4 no, look at the comment in your answer

Comment: @SW4 `input[placeholder]` won't cut it, using this means that any input with attribute placeholder will be red, in all situations, not just the placeholder.

Comment: @foxx - you're right, I've removed the answer to not pollute the thread

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Hmm yes thats weird. I guess it's a MAC thing then, im on Windows.

Comment: @HansWassink I'm on windows as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's apparently a bug:

- [Firefox 29.0 the ::-moz-placeholder css pseudo-element selector is not honored for  with type="number"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004130)

However, it seems to actually work for some users...