# Firefox placholder style on number inputs

Tags: css

Is it possible to style the placeholder of an input field with type number in firefox?

Example code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="foo">
<input type="number" placeholder="foo">
```

css:

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEtFB

In webkit the placeholder get's styled corretly. (with the webkit prefixed placeholder style)

Comment: seems to be a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512846/inputtype-number-placeholder-color-in-ff29 , https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004130

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by using below code. A working **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jiculiva/1/edit)**

```
input[type="number"]
{color:red;}
```

**Note:**

> In chrome it will not reflect until you define a initial value like below.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="foo" value="5">
```

Comment: this styles the actual color of the input field. not the placeholder