# How to change placeholder color for number input? (Firefox)

Tags: html, css

So I am aware [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) specify the color of the placeholder of an HTML `input` using CSS. However this does not seem to be working for `input` fields of type `number` in Mozilla Firefox (Works like a charm though in Chrome). Are there any workarounds for this?

**Sample HTML**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">
</div>
```

**Sample CSS**

```css
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the color of field changes the placeholder's holder to a darker shade.

Comment: possible duplicate of [input\[type=number\] placeholder color in FF29+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512846/inputtype-number-placeholder-color-in-ff29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/7x61fmgt/

---

BUT

input with type="number"
It's apparently a bug:
[Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004130)

Comment: Emmm! I have like both of those :/

Comment: Note that its just the case for `type=number`

Comment: Cool! Where do you have the info regarding the bug?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with input type number so you can use the following way currently:

```css
input[type="number"]{
  color: #f00;
}
input[type="number"]:active,input[type="number"]:focus,input[type="number"]:hover{
  color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">
</div>
```

Comment: You have `text` as type :/ My problem regards `number`