# Styling the placeholder while using -moz-appearance

Tags: css, html, firefox, placeholder

I have an element of type=number. Since I am not interested in having the spin buttons show I added the `-moz-appearance:textfield`. Now, I noticed that the placeholder styling which I setup (`::-moz-placeholder {font-style:italic}`) has stopped being applied to this field, in FireFox.

Is FireFox creating a secret element around this moz-textfield or something? Why is it not working for this particular input?

EDIT:
Now I see that it has nothing to do with the textfield. It seems that FireFox does not allow any styling for a number field (even with textfield behavior). This does work in Chrome. Any idea for a neat workaround and why indeed is this the case?

```css
input  {width: 20em}
input::-moz-placeholder  {font-style: italic; font-weight: 700; color: red}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {font-style:italic; font-weight: 700; color: red}
.hiddenspinbutton  {-moz-appearance:textfield}
.hiddenspinbutton::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<input placeholder="This is text type" type=text><br>
<input placeholder="This is number type" type=number><br>
<input placeholder="Number type without spin buttons" type=number
       class=hiddenspinbutton>
```

Comment: It's working for me!!! on ubuntu 14.04 firefox v44.0

Comment: @FarzadYZ So it's one of those things where everyone experiences something else? I feel like we are in the prehistoric times of internet development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type number Placeholder Mozilla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512846/inputtype-number-placeholder-color-in-ff29)

Comment: @Sravan OK. Pretty much. However, I'm asking for a workaround.

Comment: okay, my comment may also be helpful for you to go around a few answers written there.